# Find most frequent numbers in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I need to find the three most frequent numbers in multiple columns (named S1, S2, S3, S4, S5 and S6). I understand that I can do this using "union all", but I can't get it to work properly. Also, the number that corresponds to $id has to exist in one of the columns, but be excluded from the most frequent number list. I've tried the following code but it doesn't include the $id thing:

I actually need one more thing. There has to be a where clause that includes "where matchmal.goal = '0'" as well.

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT s1 AS tag from matchmal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s2 AS tag from matchmal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s3 AS tag from matchmal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s4 AS tag from matchmal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s5 AS tag from matchmal
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s6 AS tag from matchmal
) AS X (tag)
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[image: "Table"]

I think this should work as db example:

["Example"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f53f78)

If the $id is '91' then the output should be the number 13 and 15 as they are the most frequent numbers (they exist in both rows).

Comment: Could you provide a small data set and expected outcome?

Comment: What do you mean by "the $id thing"? I don't see that in your query

Comment: `There has to be a where clause that includes "where matchmal.goal = '0'" as well.` because you are using `GROUP BY`, you probably need `HAVING matchmail = 0`  (BTW where does the `goal` in `matchmal.goal` come from?????)

Comment: Here you can see the db structure: The column to the left is named "goal" now. [link](https://imgur.com/a/7ExAeNE)

Nico: Yeah. I can't figure out where or how to include it. If a column includes $id (f.e. if S6 is '91') then I want to know the most frequent numbers in that matching row (in column S1,S2,S3,S4,S5 and S6).

Comment: @Martin still not so clear could please give expect output as well ?

Comment: @RonakDhoot: Here's an sql fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f53f78

In that example: If the $id is '91' then the output should be the number 13 and 15 as they are the most frequent numbers (they exist in both rows). Also, the number '91' should be excluded from the search as that is the $id.

Comment: What do you mean by "the $id thing"? I don't see that in your query is still unclear after your last 'addition'...., `$id` does not exist in your fiddle....

Comment: And `18` seems to habe an equal count, comparing to `13` and `15`.  This should be made clear with example input, and output!  (see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f53f78/4))

Comment: Luuk: But as 18 is in the row with the value '1' in goal, which should not be included. Only the rows with '0' in the column 'goal' should count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirements did it using `UNION`

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT goal, s1 AS tag, count(1) AS qty FROM `matchmal` where 91 IN (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) GROUP BY s1

UNION

SELECT goal, s2 AS tag, count(1) AS qty FROM `matchmal` where 91 IN (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) GROUP BY s2

UNION

SELECT goal, s3 AS tag, count(1) AS qty FROM `matchmal` where 91 IN (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) GROUP BY s3

UNION

SELECT goal, s4 AS tag, count(1) AS qty FROM `matchmal` where 91 IN (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) GROUP BY s4

UNION

SELECT goal, s5 AS tag, count(1) AS qty FROM `matchmal` where 91 IN (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) GROUP BY s5

UNION

SELECT goal, s6 AS tag, count(1) AS qty FROM `matchmal` where 91 IN (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6) GROUP BY s6
) temp WHERE tag != 91 AND qty > 1 
ORDER BY qty DESC
```

**Output as expected**:

```
goal    tag qty
0       13  2
0       15  2
```

**Demo Refer**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f53f78/10

Comment: Thank you, Ronak!

The column "goals" need to be included as well. It needs to be set to '1' in every row. Where do I add the "where goals = '1' clause?

Also. Just a quick question since I've never done something like that. How would I join another table? I'd like to match the players table ID with the "qty" number. Ie ID 13 is Wayne Gretzky in players.id and ID 15 is Mario.Lemieux in players.id. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Martin I have updated the code for goal as well

Comment: Thanks Ronak!

Any suggestion on how to join other tables? For example join players.id (and fetch the firstname and lastname) on "tag" coumn.

Comment: I added a join query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f53f78/11 please check it

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the join query as well, worked perfectly!